# Stop the coundown timer if the user wins

Tags: javascript, html

I added a timer to my memory game, and i want to stop it when the user matches all the 8 cards.

```
window.onload = function() {
var timeoutHandle;
function countdown(minutes, seconds) {
    function tick() {
        var timecounter = document.getElementById("timer");
        timecounter.innerHTML = minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
        seconds--;
        if (seconds >= 0) {
            timeoutHandle = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        } else {
            if (minutes >= 1) {

                setTimeout(function () {
                    countdown(minutes - 1, 59);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
        if (seconds==0 && minutes ==0){

          alert("Game over");
          //reset();
        }
    }
    tick();
}

countdown(1, 00); }
```

the above is the countdown timer function

```
  if (matches == 8) {
      document.getElementById("finalMove").innerHTML = moves;
      clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

    showWinScreen();


    }
```

can you suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Since you're using `setTimeout` you should use `clearTimeout` not `clearInterval`.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen when i added the clearTimeout , the showwinscreen() is not calling. The ShowwinScreen display that user completed the game.